# WIF and ADFS 2.0 Training Examples other than Microsoft

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs2.0

Is there any good websites with examples to learn and test WIF with ADFS 2.0. (preferably ASP .NET samples) other than Microsoft resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a look at all the Microsoft stuff e.g. TechNet Wiki, Claims Based Identity & Access Control Guide etc.?

Other than that, try [Thinktecture](https://github.com/thinktecture).

Answer (score 2):

[Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com) has good training on the subject:

http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/adfs2-and-wif35
http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/iac-intro

Dominick's content is always excellent. I haven't taken the other one though.

Dominick's [blog](http://leastprivilege.com/) is full of good examples and content.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers.I am following [Vittorio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/) and Dominick's blog. It's a real treasure.